Expo Go Network Timeout SDK 51
Since I upgraded to expo sdk 51 (from sdk 50) expo go app is not loading the project on my physical device. The emulator works fine. It is showing a network timeout error. I am connected to the same network, private network enabled and have disabled all my VPN connections.
Does anyone face the same problem? I looked in the expo REPO issues but I didn't find anything similar.
I have clean my network history from my android, disabled all VPN connections, restarted the project, tested with a template project (to make sure that any dependency was causing the TIMEOUT), but still the app is not loading

Was having a very similar issue, I JUST ran

npx expo start --tunnel

and now my project is at least downloading and opening on my app, but its erroring out with some dependency issues I need to fix since npx expo install --fix doesnt do the trick
